# Reading data from Sharepoint list through PySpark

Tags: pyspark, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to read data from Sharepoint list in Pyspark using the service account and using HTTP requests.get approach but I keep getting an error "403 forbidden". That service account does have read permission to that sharepoint list and it's accessible through web browser but not accessible in Pyspark. Any advise on how to establish this connection? Is there any reference code available?

Comment: Is your PySpark solution and the web browser using the same IPs? I'm wondering if access to the Sharepoint site is IP restricted.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at how you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way the question will be clearer and it will be relatively faster for you to get a resolution as well. Thanks!